# Magento - Where do {{...}} placeholders get replaced?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.5

I'm creating some custom blocks and I want to support the *{{skin url="..."}}* dynamic placeholder features of Magento *inside* the Layout Update XML.

### Ex:

```
<action method="setImageSrc">
    <name><![CDATA[{{skin url=images/banners/MyBanner.jpg}}]]></name>
</action>
```

Inside my block class I grab the variables (i.e. `$this->getImageSrc()`), build the HTML, and output it.  Unfortunately, it's literally outputting *{{skin url="..."}}*.  Where does that translation get performed?  Is that something I can just pass my HTML through to clean it up before outputting?  If so, how?

*NOTE: I've tried with and without CDATA as well as with and without quotes around the URL.  Nothing works...some break it worse than others*

Comment: your block class could also build the URL, any helper too. Do you really need to put it in the layout file ?

Comment: See http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/cms/markup_tags#how_do_template_tags_work

Comment: Worked like a champ!  I'm going to create an answer for this based on what I've found.  Thanks for your help!  Oh, and Vince, I am putting it in the layout file because I have multiple banners and using the layout update XML is so much easier than multiple CMS Static blocks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to the information from @clockworkgeek I have figured this one out.  These 2 resources explain it very well...except how to use it.

[Magento CMS Syntax](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-cms-syntax-part1/)

[How Do Template Tags Work](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/cms/markup_tags#how_do_template_tags_work)

In order to actually use this it is VERY simple.  I simply made my own `_toHtml()` method in my custom block class as follows:

```
public function _toHtml()
{
    $processor = Mage::getModel('core/email_template_filter');
    return $processor->filter(parent::_toHtml());
}
```

Comment: That's way simply than I had imagined it. Congratulations.

Comment: It is better to post the relevant content from a foreign website to future-proof an answer, as these links no longer function as I imagine they did five years ago.